# Lucene - KeyWord Filed confusion

Tags: java, lucene

I started learning Lucene, so I am reading Lucene in Action. An excerpt from this book regarding fields is:

```
Keyword—Isn’t analyzed, but is indexed and stored in the index verbatim.
This type is suitable for fields whose original value should be preserved in
its entirety, such as URLs, file system paths, dates, personal names, Social
Security numbers, telephone numbers, and so on
```

What I understood from this is, if a text is indexed with Keyword field it is not analyzed (not split into tokens) but is indexed. However, what I don't understand is where `and stored in the index verbatim`.

I am confused about storing in the index. I assumed that if the text is indexed it will get stored in the index data structure.

Can any one please explain me with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must be reading the first edition of Lucene in Action.  That book is 11 years old and *hopelessly* outdated.  I wouldn't be inclined to worry too much about understanding the conventions of Lucene 1.4.

[The Second Edition](https://www.manning.com/books/lucene-in-action-second-edition) is available.  It's five years old and is based on Lucene 3.0, so it's definitely somewhat outdated, especially since the big changes in lucene version 4.0, but not hopelessly so.  Reading that would certainly be *much* more useful.

---

The difference between storing and indexing a field does still exist though.  In Lucene parlance:

- Index - The field is indexed, and can be searched for.  Keyword fields (Or, more recently, `StringField`) are not analyzed, but they are indexed, so their complete content can searched without tokenization.
- Store - The field is stored, in it's entirety, separately from the indexed form for later retrieval.  When you get a search result from Lucene (for instance, from [`IndexSearcher.doc(int)`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#doc(int))), the document you get back will only have stored fields in it.

As such, you can have a field that you can search on, but won't be returned in results, or a field that is returned in results but can't be searched.